# Disabling certain fields if a record exists in the database

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, database

I'm writing an application to rate posts, and the first few fields of the submission form contains basic information about the post. Right now, the first field autocompletes using jQuery UI from a MySQL db table.

I want to get to a point where if the user selects one of the autocomplete options instead of typing everything manually, the database is queried, the basic information is filled in, and the fields are disabled (to prevent duplicate entries).

I'm at a bit of a loss about the appropriate approach here. Any advice?

Thanks, Rob.

Comment: Do you have any code and/or schema you can share?  It's not really possible to provide a helpful answer without a more specific question.

Comment: can you post your code. so we can help!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `select` event of `autocomplete` to trigger an AJAX call to server.

```
$( ".selector" ).autocomplete({
    select: function( event, ui ) {
        /* data used for autocomplete is contained in ui.item... will assume you have an ID included in data object */

       $.post( url, { id:  ui.item.id), function(response){
          /* do something if needed with response from server*/
       })
   }
});
```

At server end receive the data as you would a form with a named field `id`.  `$_POST['id']`

This is very loose since not much detail has been provided in question.

API refrences:

http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#event-select

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

Comment: I realize the question was pretty vague, but thank you for being the only one who tried to give me a real answer. +1